# Obtaining size of rows using DataLength and hard-coded column names fails

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier, datalength

I am trying to write a SQL query that will show me the records that are largest in size along with the User Names associated with the record.

```
SELECT 
    Data.Id,
    User.UserName, 
    (
    ISNULL(DATALENGTH(ColumnA), 1) + 
    ISNULL(DATALENGTH(ColumnB), 1) + 
    ISNULL(DATALENGTH(ColumnC), 1)
    ) AS SizeOfRow
FROM Data
    LEFT JOIN User ON Data.UserId = User.UserId 
ORDER BY SizeOfRow DESC
```

When I run this I get the error `Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.` I am not sure where I am going wrong here. If I remove the `JOIN` to the `User` table then the SQL runs without issue. However, I really want to include the `UserName` field and I am not sure why it's addition is causing a problem.

EDIT: I should mention that `ColumnA` is a datatype of `UniqueIdentifier`. While `ColumnB` and `ColumnC` are both `varchar(max)`.

Comment: Most likely it is different datatypes across tables. Just a random guess since you didn't show us the table definition...is UserID a uniqueidentifier in one table and varchar in another?

Comment: The issue seems to be in the join, then.   What happens if you remove the DATALENGTH summation altogether, but keep the join?

Comment: @SeanLange - You are exactly correct. Is there a way to join `varchar` to `UniqueIdentifier`? Perhaps a direct cast?

Comment: OK....so do you still have a question? You would have to convert your guid to a varchar. But if it UserID why are you changing datatypes across tables? That should be a foreign key.

Comment: I did not even notice the type mismatch before Sean's answer. Should I delete the question? Is there a way to reward Sean for his help?